# JavaScript: a simple 'compare' function not working?

Tags: javascript, function

The code goes like this. It a function which takes in two parameters 'a' and 'b' and compares them both and alerts the output. But this isn't working for me!

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
function compare(a, b) {
if (a < b) {
    alert(“A is less than B”);
} else if (a > b) {
    alert(“A is greater than B”);
} else {
    alert(“A is equal to B”);
}
}

</script>
```

JsFiddle Link :http://jsfiddle.net/tTCG6/2/

Could someone please help me with it?

Comment: Well, what does it do? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and describe the behavior

Comment: @JohnKoerner  I will edit the question in just a moment

Comment: @TGH The question has been edited.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between “ " quotes in javascript?](/q/45766066/4642212), and [Simple HTML page not loading Javascript Hello World](/q/22713330/4642212).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using smart quotes (`“ ”`), which Javascript will not recognize. Use normal quotes (`" "`) instead.

The smart quotes may be because you are using a text editor that does this automatically. You should use a plaintext editor (like Notepad for Windows or TextEdit for a Mac), or use an IDE.

### [Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tTCG6/)

Comment: Thenks for helping with your answer :)